# jQuery drop down menu scrolling back up when mouse over drop down links other then the first one

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I have jQuery menu I've been working on based [on Stu Nicholls CSS multi-level drop down menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html).

I've been working on adding an animated slide down effect yet I've run into an odd problem.

When you mouse over the top level list items, the nested ul slides down. When you mouse over the first anchor link the nav stays open, yet when you mouse over any anchor links below, the ul starts to spaz out and slides up and down repeatedly.

A similar issue seems to happen if you mouse over the top level list item, and pull your mouse straight down over the drop down and then off it it quickly.

[Here is the test page I'm working on](http://webphibian.com/standards/dropdowns/index-test.php)

Any help on this issue 
would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem seems to be here

```
$('#nav ul li').hover(

  //Opens drop down
  function () { 
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#nav ul li.active ul").slideDown(200);
  },

  //Closes drop down
  function () {
    $("#nav ul li.active ul").slideUp(100);
    $(this).removeClass('active');

  }
);
```

Since you are binding to the selector `$('#nav ul li')`, and each navigation item is a separate LI, when you travel from one LI to the next, a mouseout and mouseover occurs.  I'm guessing the spazzing happens because the elements "move" during this time, causing repeated mouse over/out events to occur.

You may want to try binding to a different element, such as the UL.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I changed my binding selector to $('#nav > ul > li') so it only targets the top level list items.